# ImportError: No module named 'testApp123' django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying a sample django app. I added some changes in view.py and am trying to run migrate but it is giving following error -

```
athakur@athakur-Inspiron-7560:~/Documents/per_code/djangodemo$ python3 manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/athakur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 143, in create
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'testApp123'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/athakur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/athakur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/athakur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/athakur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/athakur/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 147, in create
    app_name, mod_path, cls_name,
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'testApp123'. Check that 'djangodemo.apps.testapp.apps.TestAppConfig.name' is correct.
```

package is correct since if I change name in TestAppConfig class to testApp it says ImportError: No module named 'testApp'.

Also following works -

```
athakur@athakur-Inspiron-7560:~/Documents/per_code/djangodemo$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from djangodemo.apps.testapp.apps import TestAppConfig
>>> TestAppConfig.name
'testApp123'
```

Any idea as to why it is still failing when I run any manage.py commands?

Directory structure is -

```
djangodemo/
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── testapp
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── migrations
│       │   └── __init__.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── apps.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│       │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

Comment: Usually it's because path to settings in your environment is wrong. It's defined in `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "djangodemo.settings")` in `manage.py`. Start by checking that.

Comment: @Borut that is correct since I have added some print statements in settings.py and it works fine.

Comment: testApp123 not exist ! when i looking for in your tree i don't see it

Comment: @rakwen it is inside the class in apps.py - `class TestAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'testApp123'`

Comment: witch version of django you use ? and where do yo take djangodemo ?

Comment: Django version : 2.0.1. Did not get your 2nd question.

Comment: I think you'll have to change your name in `apps.TestAppConfig` to `testapp`.

Comment: It was testapp only, at first does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Correct syntax is -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'djangodemo.apps.testapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
```

Not sure why https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/ says the other way.

Also to avoid djangodemo I did -

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

''' No need to reference with djangodemo after this '''
DJANGO_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.path.basename(BASE_DIR))
path.append(DJANGO_ROOT)
```

and used

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.testapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
```